# Complex sentence - words lacking?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I am striving with translating the below sentence:

> Die Wissenschaft weiss sich zu bescheiden und in die Ganzheit des Lebens einzufügen, wiewohl sie, weit entfernt, schliesslich nur als technischer Consulent für die vielfachen praktischen Zwecke der Menschen, vielmehr als Selbstzweck und zur höchsten Bestimmung des Lebens und Daseins gehörend gelten muss.

I have two questions:

1. Is there a verb lacking in the sub-sentence "schliesslich nur als technischer Consulent für die vielfachen praktischen Zwecke der Menschen"?
   Is the meaning something like "[anstatt] schliesslich nur als technischer Consulent für die vielfachen praktischen Zwecke der Menschen [fungieren]"?
2. What is the meaning of "weit entfernt" in the cited context?

Answer (score 1):

1) Yes, there is something elided, a reference to the final "gelten" is implied (.. als Consulent .. zu gelten). It sounds unusual even to this native speaker (the whole text is quite old-fashioned).
2) "weit entfernt" acts as negation and is paired with "vielmehr" as contrast / confirmation, you can read it like: not just ... but rather ...